# Calling positionViewAtIndex with the same pareamters from different points in the application provides different results

Tags: qt, qml

I need to create a fully customizable combo box. I call it the VMComboBox.

Here is the complete code for the component:

```
import QtQuick 2.6
//import QtQuick.Controls 2.3
//import QtQuick.Controls.Styles 1.4
//import QtQuick.Controls 1.4

Item {

    id: vmComboBox
    height: mainWindow.height*0.043

    property string vmErrorMsg: ""
    property bool vmEnabled: true
    property int vmMaxDisplayItems: 5
    property int vmCurrentIndex: -1
    property string vmCurrentText: ""
    property int vmListSize: 0
    readonly property int vmMOUSE_OUT_TIME: 200


    ///////////////////// FUNCTIONS
    function setModelList(list){
        itemList.clear()
        //console.log("====================================");
        for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++){
            //console.log(JSON.stringify(list[i]));
            if (typeof list[i] === 'object'){
                //console.log("Is array");
                itemList.append({"vmText": list[i]["value"], "vmIndex": i, "vmMetadata" : list[i]["metadata"], "hasMouse" : false});
            }
            else{
                //console.log("Is not array");
                itemList.append({"vmText": list[i], "vmIndex": i, "hasMouse" : false});
            }
        }
        vmListSize = list.length
        setSelection(0)
    }

    function setSelection(selectedIndex){
        vmCurrentIndex = selectedIndex;
        displayText.text = itemList.get(selectedIndex).vmText;
        vmCurrentText = displayText.text;
        mouseOutTimer.running = false;
        listContainer.visible = false;
    }

    function shouldStartDropDownTimer(hasMouse){
        if (!hasMouse){
            if (!mouseOutTimer.running){
                mouseOutTimer.running = true;
            }
        }
        else mouseOutTimer.running = false;
    }

    function dropdownHasMouse(){

        //console.log("Dropdown Has Mouse");

        for (var i = 0; i < itemList.count; i++){
            var item = itemList.get(i);
            if (item.hasMouse) {
                //console.log("Item " + i + " has the mouse");
                return; // At least one item has the mouse.
            }
        }

        // No item has the mouse, we need to check if the scroll bar has it.
        if (scrollControlMA.containsMouse) {
            //console.log("Scroll bar has the mouse");
            return ;
        }

        listContainer.visible = false;

    }

    signal selectionChanged();


    ///////////////////// DROPDOWN CLOSE CHECK TIMER
    Timer {
        id: mouseOutTimer
        interval: vmMOUSE_OUT_TIME;
        running: false;
        repeat: false
        onTriggered: {
            dropdownHasMouse()
        }
    }

    ///////////////////// THE LIST MODEL
    ListModel {
        id: itemList
    }

    ///////////////////// MAIN DISPLAY
    Rectangle {
        id: display
        anchors.fill: parent
        color: vmEnabled? "#ebf3fa" : "#bcbec0"

        // The display Text.
        Text {
            id: displayText
            text: "Test Text"
//            font.family: viewHome.robotoR.name
//            font.pixelSize: 13*viewHome.vmScale
            color: "#58595b"
            verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
            anchors.bottom: divisorLine.top
            anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
            anchors.left: parent.left
            anchors.leftMargin: mainWindow.width*0.004
        }

        // The divisor line at the bottom.
        Rectangle{
            id: divisorLine
            color: "#297fca"
            border.color: "#297fca"
            border.width: 0;
            height: 1;
            width: parent.width
            anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
        }

        // The triangle that functions as an indicator.
        Canvas {
            id: canvas
            width: mainWindow.width*0.009
            height: mainWindow.height*0.012
            anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
            anchors.right: parent.right
            anchors.rightMargin: mainWindow.width*0.004
            contextType: "2d"

            onPaint: {
                var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
                ctx.reset();
                ctx.moveTo(0, 0);
                ctx.lineTo(width, 0);
                ctx.lineTo(width / 2, height);
                ctx.closePath();
                ctx.fillStyle = "#000000";
                ctx.fill();
            }
        }

        MouseArea {
            id: mainDisplayMA
            anchors.fill: parent
            onClicked: {
                if (vmEnabled){
                    listContainer.visible = true;
                }
            }
        }

    }

    ///////////////////// DROP DOWN
    Rectangle {
        id: listContainer
        color: "#dadada"
        anchors.top: display.bottom
        anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
        width: parent.width
        height: {
            var numDisplay = vmMaxDisplayItems;
            if (numDisplay > vmListSize) {
                scrollBar.visible = false;
                numDisplay = vmListSize;
            }
            else{
                scrollBar.visible = true;
            }
            return numDisplay*vmComboBox.height;
        }
        visible: false
        clip: true

        ListView {
            id: listContainerListView
            anchors.fill: parent
            model: itemList

            onContentYChanged: {
                if (scrollBar.isScrolling) return;
                var y = (contentY - originY) * (height / contentHeight);
                scrollControl.y = y;
            }

            delegate: Rectangle {
                width: vmComboBox.width
                height: vmComboBox.height
                border.width: mainWindow.width*0.002
                border.color: "#dadada"
                color: hasMouse? "#eeeeee" : "#ffffff"

                MouseArea {
                    id: mouseItemDetector
                    anchors.fill: parent
                    hoverEnabled: true
                    propagateComposedEvents: true
                    onClicked: {
                        setSelection(vmIndex);
                        selectionChanged();
                    }
                    onContainsMouseChanged: {
                        hasMouse = containsMouse;
                        shouldStartDropDownTimer(containsMouse);
                    }
                }

                Text {
                    id: textItem
                    text: vmText
//                    font.family: viewHome.robotoR.name
//                    font.pixelSize: 13*viewHome.vmScale
                    color: "#58595b"
                    verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
                    anchors.left: parent.left
                    anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
                    anchors.leftMargin: mainWindow.width*0.004
                }
            }


        }

        Rectangle {

            id: scrollBar
            width: 0.05*listContainer.width
            height: listContainer.height
            anchors.top: listContainer.top
            anchors.right: listContainer.right
            border.color: "#dadada"
            radius: width*0.5;

            property bool isScrolling: false

            function scroll(y){
                // Doing the scroll computations.
                var totalH = vmListSize*vmComboBox.height;
                var maxScrollY = scrollControlMA.height - scrollControl.height;
                var yPosForList = totalH*y/maxScrollY
                var itemThatShouldBeVisble = Math.ceil(yPosForList/vmComboBox.height)
                console.log("Item that should be visible: " + itemThatShouldBeVisble)
                listContainerListView.positionViewAtIndex(itemThatShouldBeVisble,ListView.End)

            }

            MouseArea {
                id: scrollControlMA
                anchors.fill: parent
                hoverEnabled: true
                onContainsMouseChanged: {

                    // Making sure that no item has the mouse.
                    // This should not be necessary but for some reason the delegates of the list view sometimes do not detect when the mouse leaves them.
                    for (var i = 0; i < itemList.count; i++){
                        itemList.setProperty(i,"hasMouse",false);
                    }

                    shouldStartDropDownTimer(containsMouse);
                }

                drag.target: scrollControl
                drag.axis: Drag.YAxis
                drag.minimumY: 0
                drag.maximumY: scrollControlMA.height - scrollControl.height

                drag.onActiveChanged: {
                    if (drag.active){
                        scrollBar.isScrolling = true;
                    }
                    else{
                        scrollBar.isScrolling = false;
                    }
                }

                onClicked: {
                    // If the click falls inside the scroll controller, then it is ignored.
                    var y = mouseY
                    var maxY = (scrollBar.height - scrollControl.height);
                    if ( (y > scrollControl.y) && (y < (scrollControl.y + scrollControl.height)) ) return;

                    if (scrollBar.isScrolling) return;

                    y = y - scrollControl.height/2;
                    if (y < 0) y = 0;
                    if (y > maxY) y = maxY;

                    scrollControl.y = y;
                    console.log("Scroll click is " + y);
                    scrollBar.scroll(y)

                }

            }

            Rectangle {
                id: scrollControl
                width: parent.width
                height: {
                    var maxH = parent.height;
                    var scale = vmMaxDisplayItems/vmListSize;
                    if (scale > 1) return parent.height;
                    if (scale < 0.08) scale = 0.08;
                    return parent.height*scale
                }

                radius: scrollBar.radius

                color: "#dadada"
                onYChanged: {
                    if (!scrollBar.isScrolling) return;
                    console.log("On moving Scroll Bar: " + y);
                    scrollBar.scroll(y)
                }
            }

        }

    }

    //////////////////// THE ERROR MESSAGE
    Text{
        id: errorMsg
        text: vmErrorMsg
        color:  "#ca2026"
//        font.family: viewHome.robotoR.name
//        font.pixelSize: 12*viewHome.vmScale
        anchors.left: parent.left
        anchors.top: parent.bottom
        anchors.topMargin: mainWindow.height*0.007
        z: vmComboBox.z - 1
        visible: (vmErrorMsg !== "")
    }

}
```

And here is the test case:

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Window 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0

Window {

    id: mainWindow

    visible: true
    //visibility: Window.Maximized
    width: 1000
    height: 800
    title: qsTr("Hello World")


    VMComboBox {
        id: testbox
        width: 839.0399999999997
        height: 89.31099999999999
        anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
        anchors.top: parent.top
        anchors.topMargin: 20
        Component.onCompleted: {

            var list = []
            //for (var i = 0; i < 8; i++){
            for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++){
                list.push("Item " + i);
            }

            testbox.setModelList(list);

        }
    }


}
```

My problem is in the scrollBar.scroll (y) function. If the function is called while scrolling (this means dragging the square in the scroll bar) I get the following print out, when scrolling to the bottom:

```
qml: On moving Scroll Bar: 409
qml: Item that should be visible: 100
qml: On moving Scroll Bar: 410
qml: Item that should be visible: 100
qml: On moving Scroll Bar: 410.83059999999995
qml: Item that should be visible: 100
```

This is called on the onYChanged method of the scrollControl reactangle. This way the ComboBox behaves as expected and the Listview is updated by the positionViewAtIndex function correctly,.

My problem comes when I click the empty bar. The function is called from the onClicked of the scrollControlMA (or mouse area). When this happens near the very bottom of the scroll bar, I get this print out

```
qml: Scroll click is 410.83059999999995
qml: Item that should be visible: 100
```

But when I do this positionViewAtIndex does not update the list view, remaining where it is. And the what's worst, when I click anywhere else other than the bottom, the list view gets updated as expected.

What drives me really insae is the fact that both times the positionViewAtIndex is called with the exact same parameter both times. And it is only called once because it's not anywhere else in the code and the message right above where it's called is only called only appears once when I click. So the behaviour makes absolutely no sense.

Comment: Btw, you can _fully_ customize the standard `ComboBox` item, see it [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquickcontrols2-customize.html#customizing-combobox)

Comment: I'll check it out. Thank you! Do you know if you can also cusotmized the the Scroll Bar?, Becuase I was asked to make the wider.

Comment: I guess you can , see the `ScrollIndicator` inside the `contentItem` in the example.

Comment: Ok. Great. If can't solve this issue, I will start from scratch and go down this route. Thanks!